# Mouse event not registering in <object> inside <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a Flash `<object>` embed that is inside (first child of) a container `<div>`; the container div has the following properties (essential attributes summarized):

`position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2;`

There is a full-screen canvas at z-index 0. Now when I bind an event handler to the `<div>` I can confirm that it receives mouse events, but the `<object>` embed remains unresponsive.

Any ways I can troubleshoot/figure out what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Flash objects usually take control of the mouse. I don't know if there is any way around this.

Comment: How do you mean "unresponsive" ... did you attach javascript events to the `<object>`? If so, I'm guessing that Flash is gobbling up the click event, and I don't think the event will bubble up from Flash to the DOM. At that point, your only option is to handle the click event in your Flash, and if you have to have DOM interaction, you need to look at the ExternalInterface documentation, here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: @mori57 No I am not interested in attaching javascript events to the object. I just mean the user cannot interact with the object (it is a flash video container with some controls), for example pressing the play button (which is in flash not the HTML).

Comment: @AndrewLee - Have you assigned a width and height to the DIV that contains the Flash object? with overflow:hidden, it might be blocking the event before it gets to the child-Flash object. More code would be helpful, to further troubleshoot this one, if you can spare it.

Comment: @mori57 Yes there is an explicit width and height on the DIV...question has been edited. I will post some more code soon.

Comment: @AndrewLee - If that's an exact copy, I see the problem. Add "px" to your width and height values: `width: 100px; height: 100px` Without specifying the unit, the CSS spec for dimensions is ignored.

Comment: @mori57 Oops, it actually did have the "px" I just copied wrong...edited again

Answer (score 0):

try setting wmode="transparent" in your embed/object properties